# Checking a Menu Item from PopUpMenu returns NullPointer

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, menuitem, popupmenu

In my menu xml I have this:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_payoff"
    android:visible="true"
    android:checkable="true"/>
```

In my `adapter`'s `getView()` method, where each menu item has the same `PopUpMenu`, I do this:

```
    holder.ib.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(getContext(), v);
            popup.getMenu().findItem(R.id.action_payoff).setChecked(true);
```

I get a `NullPointerException`.  When I remove the `setChecked(true);` all works fine (of course my checkbox in my `PopUpMenu` item is not checked)

Does anyone have thoughts on this?

Sidenote:  There is some logic that is not built in yet, of course.  I was simply trying to access the menu item programatically before I connect it conditionally with a `SharedPreference`.

Comment: But why do you expect that it won't return `null`? Pretty obviously there is not such an `MenuItem` in `PopupMenu`'s `Menu`, you haven't performed anything in order to include that item in `PopupMenu`.

Comment: @azizbekian I would not consider it obvious.  When that part of the line is removed (but not the xml) there is a menu item with a checkbox and with that id

Comment: @azizbekian Anyhow, it is fixed now, I moved that line until after the popup `show()`

Answer (score 2):

I fixed it by moving the line of code AFTER the `show()` method, like so:

```
popup.show();                
popup.getMenu().findItem(R.id.action_include_payoff).setChecked(true);
```

Comment: place it just BEFORE the `popup.show(); ` will also do the job. anyways Thanks